# Jmeter & browser concurrent requests showing different results?

Tags: jmeter

When I have given 500 concurrent users load via jmeter my server throwing error message but the same time I have called same request via browser showing proper response. How it is possible? Is there any settings in jmeter for avoiding same.

Comment: What error message your server is throwing? I think your problem is client side (e.g. low bandwidth)

Comment: are requests _exactly_ the same (including headers, cookie presence and parameters)?

Comment: @Kiril yes Requests are exactly same including header, Cookie & parameters

Comment: @ViaSat, server side error usually comes while exceed load on server.

Answer (score 3):

It is hard to say what can go wrong without seeing your JMeter configuration, full server response, JMeter and application under test logs and network dump for browser and JMeter.

The whole idea of performance testing is mimicking real user as close as possible, so you need at least

1. Add [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) and set JMeter to:

   - Download embedded resources
   - Use concurrent pool of 2-5 threads
2. Add [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager)
3. Add [HTTP Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager)
4. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager)
5. Correlate any dynamic parameters
6. Simulate any specific application behaviour (i.e. AJAX calls)
7. etc.

In addition to above recommendations: ideally given "good" JMeter you shouldn't see any "response messages", you should see a number of errors in final report so double check you:

- Run JMeter in non-GUI mode
- Storing only those metrics which are absolutely required
- Follow other recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure)

Comment: thanks for helping hand. let me recheck its request issue or response.

Answer (score 0):

beside, what Dmitri described above, I would also check the actual throughput the server returns in either cases.

Throughput depends a lot on the timers you configured in Jmeter to simulate think time.
Jmeter has no rendering and no javascript engine, so each thread is much much faster than a real browser.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been busy lately. Yes, if your server can safely handle say 100 req/s, you will get errors while exceeding that figure. From your question, is not clear to me if your script works well with few users (i.e. threads).